# How do I use java to fetch dynamic web content?

Tags: java, fetch, weather

I've been programming in java for a little while and I've found no real way to even come close to this goal.   My googling has been pretty fruitless as well.

I'm looking for a way to essentially download current weather (or other but weather is a good start I suppose) and save the current temp / humidity / dewpoint / next day forecast for those numbers into an array of strings

I have no idea where to start, but I figure that this will be a good place to start learning how to use java to fetch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good source for weather information is [METAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAR). There is also a Java library [jweather](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jweather/) available which should encapsulate all network/protocol/api issues to a limited set of methods to retrieve the required weather information

Answer (score 3):

How would you approach this task in other language?

In the case of weather you would probably look for some API exposed by the site you're trying to get the weather from.
Here come some clues:
1. If you want to just issue an HTTP request, get a result (kind-of ajax style) and parse the web page you can use java.net package or if you want a (much more powerful) thirdparty lib, use Apache HTTP Client.
2. If you're looking for API exposed via WebServices (which I believe is a better approach here) then they're language agnostic, so you just turn to web services (SOAP/Rest) in Java just like in any other language.

I know, the answer is a little bit 'common', so please clarify 'how' are you planning to solve this issue (even in any other language)...

Hope, this helps

Comment: Well, realistically I'm not opposed to any specific method of getting data, so long as I'm able to use it in a larger program.  Thus having it in some kind of text / xml / csv / db file would likely be preferable.   Aside from that little tid-bit I'm not opposed to how it gets there.